# mysql json where clause

Tags: mysql, json, sqldatatypes, mysql-8.0

I have a table with the below json data type column in a table PRICING_DATA

```
pricingJson type json nullable
```

And I am using the sql to query the table.

```
select * from `PRICING_DATA` where `pricingJson`->"$.product.productFamily" = "Compute Instance";
```

The sample json data is like below

```
{
"product": {
    "productFamily": "Compute Instance",
    "attributes": {
        "enhancedNetworkingSupported": "Yes",.....
```

But the query is not returning any rows.
What am I doing wrong here?

Json raw string from the db seems escaped.

```
"{\"product\":{\"productFamily\":\"Compute Instance\",\"attributes\":{\"enhancedNetworkingSupported\":\"Yes
```

I have used the below json unquote but still it is not giving me any rows.

```
select * from `PRICING_DATA` where JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(pricingJson, "$.product.productFamily")) = "Compute Instance";
```

Comment: Works for me: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bd42bbb37fc3f5bcb6af7024e595ba71 Perhaps you have some weird characters in your values?

Comment: @Nick : You are right, this was those backslash characters indeed. I will update the post to show the fix.

Answer (score 8):

You need to "unquote" the JSON string in order to compare it.

```
select * from `PRICING_DATA` where `pricingJson`->>"$.product.productFamily" = "Compute Instance";
```

Docs: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-inline-path

---

Using `pricingJson->"$.product.productFamily"` is shorthand for

```
JSON_EXTRACT(pricingJson, "$.product.productFamily")
```

which returns the value, but as a *quoted* string.  So:

```
SELECT pricingJson->"$.product.productFamily" FROM PRICING_DATA
```

would return:

```
+-----------------------------------------+
| pricingJson->"$.product.productFamily"  |
+-----------------------------------------+
| "Compute Instance"                      |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

You need to remove the quotes with the `JSON_UNQUOTE()` function, and using `pricingJson->>"$.product.productFamily"` is shorthand for:

```
JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(pricingJson, "$.product.productFamily"))
```

Comment: What makes you think this? OPs code works perfectly fine in my demo https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bd42bbb37fc3f5bcb6af7024e595ba71

Comment: I think there is an escaped json issue. In DB I see Json entries are escaped.