# Use JSON array in MYSQL WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

Can someone help me please with the correct syntax. I have a JSON  array of product codes and want to pass that to mysql to search for each ones ID

```
["3300-0021-PC","PRIMA802","3633-6021\/4","3652-5023\/3","3652-5021\/3","3652-5022\/3","3652-5024\/3"]
```

my sql query

```
SELECT
p.id,
p.name FROM
p_product p WHERE
p.name IN ('3633-0002', '3633-0052')
AND p.deleted = 0
```

I want to use the JSON array in the WHERE clause. I could alter the string to make it work but wandered if there was a more efficient  / correct way to use a JSON array using something like JSON_EXTRACT. I am using MYSQL 5.7. I have looked at [mysql json where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56188209/mysql-json-where-clause) but my array is not an accusative array, thanks.

I have tried using this method in my code as below

```
public function productsArray($api, $args) 
{
    $test = array("3300-0021-PC","PRIMA802","3633-6021/4","3652-5023/3","3652-5021/3");
    $test = json_encode($test);

    $db         = $GLOBALS['db']->getConnection();
    $result     = [];
    $rowData    = [];

    $query .= "SELECT
        p.id,
        p.name
    FROM
        p_product p
    WHERE
        JSON_SEARCH(".$test.", 'one', p.name) IS NOT NULL
        AND p.deleted = ?";

    $stmt = $db->executeQuery($query, array(0));

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $row) {
            foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
                $rowData[$key] = $val;
            }
            $result['records'][] = $rowData;
        }
        $result['Total'] = $stmt->rowCount();
        return $result;
    }
    return false;
}
```

this is throwing an SQL error, Do you have to SET a json array before using it in a query?

Comment: @Akina, thankyou for that, does the 'one' tell sql to start at the beginning of the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM p_product p
WHERE JSON_SEARCH(@j, 'one', p.name) IS NOT NULL;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=62fbd3c32b12ce66f19fea0b2a5f4d4c)

---

> does the 'one' tell sql to start at the beginning of the array?

`'one'` means "find first occurence" - this is enough for your task.

Comment: i was trying to implement your method but its throwing an sql error do I need to SET a json array before using it?

Comment: @John `@j` is a placeholder. You may use user-defined or local variable with your JSON, a column of some table, or insert string literal containing your JSON (directly by substitution or as prepared statement parameter) instead - this is your choice.

Comment: @Aklina, thanks for the reply, thought it would be a placeholder just strange how I get an error when I place it in as a string, will try it as a prepared variable

Comment: @John Show final query text (after substitution) and error message (unchanged and non-shortened).

Answer (score 0):

All working now passing the json array via a prepared statment

```
    public function productsArray($api, $args) 
{
    $test = array("3300-0021-PC","PRIMA802","3633-6021/4","3652-5023/3","3652-5021/3");

    $db         = $GLOBALS['db']->getConnection();
    $result     = [];
    $rowData    = [];

    $query .= "SELECT
        p.id,
        p.name
    FROM
        p_product p
    WHERE
        JSON_SEARCH(?, 'one', p.name) IS NOT NULL
        AND p.deleted = ?";

    $stmt = $db->executeQuery($query, array(json_encode($test), 0));

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
        foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $row) {
            foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
                $rowData[$key] = $val;
            }
            $result['records'][] = $rowData;
        }
        $result['Total'] = $stmt->rowCount();
        return $result;
    }
    return false;
}
```